# Integrate jBPM with Optaplanner

Tags: jbpm, optaplanner

how can I integrate jBPM with OptaPlanner. I have solved a problem using OptaPlanner, where there are a number of requests which are optimally assigned to particular employees, based on certain constraints. Now I want to create a dispatcher in jBPM, where certain employees(actors) can solve certain requests(process instances). Any idea how I can go about this problem ?

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: So the JBPM human task assignments are a **task assignment problem** you want to solve with OptaPlanner? Kris and I spoke about building some out-of-the-box integration/docs for this. But for now you 'll have to do the integration yourself. OptaPlanner is being successfully used for [other task assignment problems](http://www.optaplanner.org/learn/caseStudies/OptaPlannerCaseStudy_RJV_2013-06-14.pdf) already.

Answer (score 1):

There is no much that you need to do in order to integrate them, because they are already integrated. You just need to define what do you want to achieve. Are the processes requiring the rules or the rules calling new processes?

Regards

Comment: Drools is integrated in jBPM. OptaPlanner is not yet integrated in jBPM, as far as I know. But there's nothing preventing it, such as in the way salaboy suggests :)